# How to tile an image in Blend for Visual Studio 2012/13

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, blend, tile, brush

I'm having a lot of trouble figuring out how to do something incredibly simple... I just want to fill a rectangle with a tiled image (texture).

It seems like it should be easy enough, using a TileBrush. However, the 'TileMode' property/option is just not there.

It should be as easy as this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh134804(v=expression.40).aspx

But in reality, I can't get it working at all. Has anyone had any luck doing this in Blend?

Answer (score 0):

The option isn't available in this blend version. probably because tilemode is not (yet?) available in WinRT and this blend seems to be made for Windows 8 apps.

The old blend can do it for WPF apps but it was never available for Windows Phone and WinRT.